# different decoration for pieces of the path between dots in svg

Tags: svg

Situation: have a dynamically defined path e.g.

```
<path class="view-sequence-path" marker-start="url(#svg-marker-start)" marker-end="url(#svg-marker-end)" d="M 649,340 Q741,314 699.5,308 Q658,302 702,289 Q746,276 708,251.5 Q670,227 706,210.5 Q742,194 700.5,187.5 Q659,181 681,156.5 Q703,132 674,125.5 Q645,119 658,105 L671,91"></path>
```

that connects dots in a smooth way with . So, i would like to sustain smoothness of the curve, but make some pieces decorated differently e.g. make dashed. What is the possible easiest way to do that?

Comment: You'll need to create separate path elements if you want to style them differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [custom strokedasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) in order to change the dash pattern within a path. Ordinarily these are used to create a repeating pattern, but you can define a long pattern that is equal to the length of your path and hence customize down to the pixel level.